# PHP создание элемента массива

Tags: php, массивы, symfony2, синтаксис

Добрый вечер. Начал изучать Symfony 2, и пытаюсь разобрать кусок кода, который отвечает за подключение бандлов (модулей).

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
);
```

Что тут делает оператор new? Создание переменной? Почему далее идут слэши? Почему строка заканчивается "()" - как будто это функция?

Такое вижу в первый раз, расскажите, пожалуйста, в подробностях что это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю - тут создаётся объект класса + указывается полный путь к нужному классу(неймспейс). Это создано для того, чтобы в случае одинаковых названий классов не было бы конфликтов.

http://www.php.net//manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Теперь всё понятно. Благодарю.